# symfony2: Problems after installing PUGXMultiUserBundle

Tags: symfony

I have installed PUGXMultiUserBundle for using multi-users in my symfony project (buyers and sellers). After installing PUGXMultiUserBundle, I create the abstract class and the 2 entities that inherit the abstract class (Seller,Buyer).

When I try to update the database by running the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I have the following errors:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
The service definition "fos_user.registration.form.factory" does not exist.
```

How do I fix this issue?